# Why were some scenes changed in Pioneer One?

Tags: pioneer-one

I've recently re-watched the pilot episode for [Pioneer One](http://www.pioneerone.tv/) with a friend before watching the episode 2. I was really confused as the pilot episode that I had to re-download was changed. Specially the initial scenes at a radio-telescope were totally missing and instead we see a pilot and a couple witnessing the *falling object*.

What happened? Why were they changed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Creators appear to have deleted some scenes, but they plan to add them back in a new release.
At least, according to [this article here on November 15, 2010](http://gigaom.com/video/pioneer-one-trailblazes-a-new-path-to-tvs/).  [This YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hN49juALYgI) has the deleted scenes, which appear to be scenes 2 and 3 from the original pilot.